# CSOM move document from SharePoint list to OneDrive

Tags: sharepoint, office365, onedrive, sharepoint-online

I'd like to move documents from document library in SharePoint Online to my OneDrive using CSOM. I searched several topics but there is no relevant answer. Just wondering is it possible?

Comment: Does it have to be CSOM? Why not use Flow?

Comment: Since my project is using CSOM at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **SP.MoveCopyUtil.moveFolder** and **SP.MoveCopyUtil.moveFile** ?

MethodS takes 3 parameters,

- context – current context
- source url – Full source url of the file / folder.
- destination url – Full destination url of the file / folder.

**SP.MoveCopyUtil.moveFolder:**

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
SP.MoveCopyUtil.moveFolder(context,"http://sp2016/sitepages/homeFolder","http://sp2016/pages/HomeFolder1");
context.executeQueryAsync(function(){},function(){});
```

**SP.MoveCopyUtil.moveFile:**

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
SP.MoveCopyUtil.moveFile(context,"http://sp2016/sitepages/home1.aspx","http://sp2016/pages/home1.aspx");
context.executeQueryAsync(function(){},function(){});
```

The above api’s are available within O365.

The equivalent CSOM api is also available within the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.MoveCopyUtil.